# named tuple from dictionary using double-star-operator: are nested fields unpacked too?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, argument-unpacking

I have two classes: *Top* and *Nested*, and to create both of them I need to provide *TopDefinition* and *NestedDefinition* objects, which are of type **NamedTuple** (definitions are required for type annotations). And Class *Top* contains attribute, which is a list of *Nested* instances objects.

There is a nested dict which is used to create instance of named tuple.
The input dict `item` looks like below:

```
type =<class 'dict'>
value={'t1': 'qwe', 't2': 'QWE', 't3': [{'n1': 'aaa', 'n2': 1}, {'n1': 'bb', 'n2': 3}]}
```

Then it is unpacked to create instance of class *TopDefinition* with the code

`q = Top(top=TopDefinition(**item))`
to be used as input to create instance of the class *Top*. and this works well, I can later see in the *q* class type and value of input param:

```
type=<class '__main__.TopDefinition'>
value=TopDefinition(t1='qwe', t2='QWE', t3=[{'n1': 'aaa', 'n2': 1}, {'n1': 'bb', 'n2': 3}])
```

that TopDefinition instance is properly created as named tuple with fields: t1, t2, t3.

**The question is: what is t3 type of?**
Is it a list of dicts or is the list of named tuples (implicitly converted, because it is defined in *TopDefinition* as *List[NestedTuple]*?
The output suggest that this is a list of dicts, because when I iterate over t3, displaying type and value, I see:

```
type=<class 'dict'>,
value={'n1': 'aaa', 'n2': 1}
Is named_tuple=False
```

Then I unpack `{'n1': 'aaa', 'n2': 1}` with ** to create *NestedDefinition* instance which works OK, so it should be a dict.
On the other hand mypy (with options --ignore-missing-imports --strict) says `error: Argument after ** must be a mapping` which means to me that it is not a dict.

Full code, to run is below:

```
"""Replicate the problem."""
from typing import Any, List, NamedTuple


class NestedDefinition(NamedTuple):
    """Nested object metadata for mypy type annotation."""

    n1: str
    n2: int


class TopDefinition(NamedTuple):
    """Top object metadata for mypy type annotation."""

    t1: str
    t2: str
    t3: List[NestedDefinition]


def isnamedtupleinstance(x: Any) -> bool:
    """Check if object is named tuple."""
    t = type(x)
    b = t.__bases__
    print("-------{}".format(b))
    if len(b) != 1 or b[0] != tuple:
        return False
    f = getattr(t, '_fields', None)
    if not isinstance(f, tuple):
        return False
    return all(type(n) == str for n in f)


class Nested:
    """Nested object."""

    n1: str
    n2: int

    def __init__(self, nested: NestedDefinition) -> None:
        print("{cName} got:\n\ttype={y}\n\tvalue={v}\n\tIS named_tuple: {b}".format(
            cName=type(self).__name__, y=type(nested), v=nested, b=isnamedtupleinstance(nested)))
        self.n1 = nested.n1
        self.n2 = nested.n2


class Top:
    """Top object."""

    t1: str
    t2: str
    t3: List[Nested]

    def __init__(self, top: TopDefinition) -> None:
        print("{cName} got:\n\ttype={y}\n\tvalue={v}".format(cName=type(self).__name__,
                                                             y=type(top), v=top))

        self.t1 = top.t1
        self.t2 = top.t2
        self.t3 = []
        if top.t3:
            for sub_item in top.t3:
                print("Nested passing:\n\ttype={t},\n\tvalue={v}\n\tIs named_tuple={b}".format(
                    t=type(sub_item), v=sub_item, b=isnamedtupleinstance(sub_item)))
                nested = Nested(nested=NestedDefinition(**sub_item))
                self.addNestedObj(nested)

    def addNestedObj(self, nested: Nested) -> None:
        """Append nested object to array in top object."""
        self.t3.append(nested)


def build_data_structure(someDict: List) -> None:
    """Replicate problem."""
    for item in someDict:
        print("Top passing:\n\ttype ={type}\n\tvalue={value}".format(
            type=type(item), value=item))
        w = Top(top=TopDefinition(**item))


x = [
    {
        't1': 'qwe',
        't2': 'QWE',
        't3': [
            {'n1': 'aaa', 'n2': 1},
            {'n1': 'bb', 'n2': 3}
        ]
    },
    {
        't1': 'asd',
        't2': 'ASD',
        't3': [
            {'n1': 'cc', 'n2': 7},
            {'n1': 'dd', 'n2': 9}
        ]
    }
]


build_data_structure(someDict=x)
```

Comment: No, `**` does not apply to values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type hints are there for static type checking. They do not affect runtime behaviour.

The `**mapping` syntax in a call only expands the top-level key-value pairs; it's as if you called

```
TopDefinition(t1='qwe', t2='QWE', t3=[{'n1': 'aaa', 'n2': 1}, {'n1': 'bb', 'n2': 3}])
```

The object called is not given any information on the source of those keyword arguments; the `namedtuple` class `__new__` method doesn't care and can't care how the keyword arguments were set.

So the list remains unchanged, it is not converted for you. You'd have to do so *up front*:

```
def build_data_structure(someDict: List[Mapping]) -> None:
    for item in someDict:
        print("Top passing:\n\ttype ={type}\n\tvalue={value}".format(
            type=type(item), value=item))

        t3updated = []
        for nested in item['t3']:
            if not isinstance(nested, NestedDefinition):
                nested = NestedDefinition(**nested)
            t3updated.append(nested)
        item['t3'] = t3updated
        w = Top(top=TopDefinition(**item))
```

Because you used a `**mapping` call, static type analysers such as mypy can't determine that your list does not match the `List[NestedDefinition]` type hint, and won't alert you to it, but if you used the full call explicitly using separate arguments as I did above, then you'd get an error message telling you that you are not using the correct types.

In mypy, you could also use the [`TypedDict` type definition](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict) to document what type of mappings the list passed to `build_data_structure()` contains, at which point mypy can deduce that your `t3` values are lists of dictionaries, not lists of your named tuple.

Next, the `error: Argument after ** must be a mapping` error that `mypy` is giving you is based on the *type hints* that `mypy` has access to, not on runtime information. Your loop:

```
for sub_item in top.t3:
```

tells `mypy` that in **correct code**, `sub_item` **must** be a `NestedDefinition` object, because the `t3: List[NestedDefinition]` tells it so. And a `NestedDefinition` object is not a mapping, so the `sub_item` reference can't be used in a `**mapping` call.

The fact that you snuck in some actual mappings via the opaque `TopDefinition(**item)` calls in `build_data_structure()` (where those `item` objects come from an unqualified `List`) is neither here nor there; `mypy` can't know what type of object `item` is and so can't make any assertions about the values either.

Comment: Based on Your answer, instead of doing it upfront, I simply added checking if `sub_item` is instance of dict in the Top.__init__.: 
`if isinstance(sub_item, dict):
    nested = Nested(nested=NestedDefinition(**sub_item))`